# Joint probability mass function for series of coin flips

Tags: probability, statistics, functions, random-variables

A fair coin is rolled until at least two heads and at least two tails are obtained. Let
the random variable X denote the roll in which the second head is obtained and let the
random variable Y denote the roll in which the second tail is obtained.

How do I find the joint probability mass function of X and Y?

I don't know how to start this question.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If $X=n$ and $Y=m$ then there was precisely one head in $\{1,...,n-1\}$ i.e. the rest were tails, but on the other hand there was only one tail in $\{1,...,m-1\}$ so the rest were heads. That severely restricts what at least one of $n,m$ can be. Think along these lines.

Comment: Observe that $\min(X,Y)$ only takes values in $\{2,3\}$ and $\max(X,Y)\geq4$. Secondly that $P(X=n,Y=m)=P(X=m,Y=n)$. So it is enough to find $P(X=2,Y=n)$ and $P(X=3,Y=n)$ for $n\geq4$.

Comment: @drhab Hi, do you mind explaining a bit more on how I can find the probabilities?

Thanks

Comment: @drhab Please correct me if I'm wrong. To find $P(X=2, Y=n)$ and $P(X=3, Y=n)$, do I use the geometric distribution with probability p=0.5? Thanks!

Comment: Let me give you an example for $n=8$. Then $X=3,Y=8$ only by outcomes HTHHHHHT and THHHHHHT so the probability on that is $2\cdot2^{-8}$. For $X=2,Y=8$ things are a bit more complicated. There are $5=8-3$ corresponding outcomes: HHTHHHHT, HHHTHHHT, HHHHTHHT, HHHHHTHT and HHHHHHTT. So probability is $5\cdot2^{-8}$.

Comment: Can you give me a hint how to display this in tabular form if you dont mind? @drhab

Comment: No, that is really not my territory. I am a theory guy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the first two outcome is $HH$, then we have $X=2$, the smallest value that $Y$ can take is $4$.

Similarly, if the first two outcome is $TT$, then we have $Y=2$, the smallest value that $X$ can take is $4$.

If the first two outcome is $HT$ or $TH$,  then $\min(X,Y)=3$.

That is we have $\min(X,Y) \in \{2, 3\}$ and $\max(X,Y) \ge 4$.

Let $n \ge 4$.

To compute $P(X=2, Y=n)$, the first two tosses $H$, the last outcome is $T$, from the $3$rd to $(n-1)$-th outcome, there is exactly one $T$.

That is consider $$HHW\ldots WT$$

where we have $n-3$ $W$'s, we have to choose $1$ of them to be $T$. We have $\binom{n-3}{1} = n-3$. The probability to get a particular sequence is $\frac1{2^n}$, hence the corresponding probability is

$$P(X=2, Y=n) = \frac{n-3}{2^n}$$

We also have $P(X=n, Y=2) = P(X=2, Y=n)$ by symetry.

Now, let's compute $P(X=3, Y=n)$, in this case, the first two tosses is either $HT$ or $TH$, the third position must be $H$, the last position is $T$. The remaining position must be $H$.

Hence we have

$$P(X=3, Y=n)=\frac{2}{2^n}$$

We have $P(X=n, Y=3) = P(X=3, Y=n)$ by symmetry.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. And I can just transform this into tabular form am I right?

Comment: $n$ can be arbitrarily large though.

Comment: Note however the decay is exponential, it becomes small very quickly

Comment: So does this mean the joint pmf only takes $P(X=2,Y=n)$ and $P(X=3, Y=n)$? Can you also explain a bit more how you got the probabilities? I'm quite lost sorry

Comment: added more details. we only have to focus on $P(X=2, Y=n)=P(X=n, Y=2)$ and $P(X=3, Y=n)=P(X=n, Y=3) $, the rest are $0$.

Comment: How would you write this in the usual joint probability mass function notation. For example, Px,y(x, y) = ???